# Android: Google Places API getAutocompletePredictions with language support

Tags: android, google-places-api

I need to search for places and get results in a specified language.
The Places API has a [language support](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#language-param) when using a url query.
I would like to use the `Android` API (`Places Autocomplete`), meaning something like

```
     PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter, "pl");
```

Clearly, the last parameter ("pl" stands for Polish) can't be used as this method doesn't exists..

I thought about using the [filter](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get-predictions), but it doesn't seem to have this option.

Any ideas? Thx.

**Edit**
Seems like the results are returned in the same language that the query was written,  which is actually pretty cool:)

Comment: Why do you want autocomplete results in a language other than the users default language?

Comment: Because the user can set an app-specific language.

Comment: I have the same problem in ios.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the default locale to the app's language seems to do the trick. I added the code  below in my base activity class, which all activities extend. It might also be fine just to add it in your class that extends Application (if you don't have a "switch language live" option)

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Note: I set the locale before calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Comment: does it.?  Cant notice any change. Actually,  seems like the results are returned in the same language that the query was written,  which ia actually pretty cool:)